# get list of years/months/days/hours between two dates in scala

Tags: list, scala, date

I have the following two dates and I want a scala function which returns a list of months between the two dates like 31-12-2019 and 01-02-2020.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What is the wanted output? What have you tried?

Comment: What output would you like to have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `java.time` library.

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

val start = LocalDate.parse("31-12-2019"
                           ,DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"))
val stop  = LocalDate.parse("01-02-2020"
                           ,DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"))

LazyList.iterate(start)(_.plusMonths(1))
        .takeWhile(_.isBefore(stop.plusMonths(1)))
        .toList
        .map(_.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM")))
//res0: List[String] = List(2019-12, 2020-01, 2020-02)
```

Notice that "month" is only mentioned twice, as `.plusMonths()`. Change those to `.plusDays()` or `.plusYears()` and it all works as expected. Of course the output presentation format will have to be adjusted as required.

Answer (score 1):

It can look like this

```
import org.joda.time._

@tailrec
def findMonths(dt: DateTime, lastDt: DateTime, months: List[String] = Nil): List[String] = {
  val formatter = format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMMM, yyyy")
  val nextMonth = dt.plusMonths(1)
  if (nextMonth.isBefore(lastDt.getMillis))
    findMonths(nextMonth, lastDt, months :+ formatter.print(nextMonth))
  else
    months
}

val res = findMonths(
  DateTime.parse("2019-12-31"), 
  DateTime.parse("2020-04-01")
)
println(res) // List("january, 2020", "february, 2020", "march, 2020")
```